# Why does clang -MM output a Windows-style absolute path with a colon, which is invalid for make rule syntax?

Tags: cygwin, c-preprocessor, llvm-clang, gnu-make

Regarding the MM flag:

> Instead of outputting the result of preprocessing, output a rule
>   suitable for make describing the dependencies of the main source file.
>   The preprocessor outputs one make rule containing the object file name
>   for that source file, a colon, and the names of all the included
>   files, including those coming from -include or -imacros command line
>   options.

The version of clang I'm using is part of the Android NDK and as such uses Windows-style paths, rather than Cygwin-style paths. Using the `-MM` flag, clang is outputting the name of an included files as an absolute, Windows-style path which has a colon after the drive letter, thus breaking the syntax that Cywgin's GNU Make is expecting.

I could adjust the paths after clang outputs it and before make uses it, but this seems like a hack, as the `-MM` flag is not producing appropriate output (a valid make rule). Is there a flag or environment variable to correct this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some variants of make do support unescaped colons in Windows-style absolute paths as part of a make rule, but the GNU make in Cygwin does not - which is [a known fact](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2006-07/msg00671.html). The output from clang is not invalid for other variants of make (MSYS for MinGW) which support this behavior. Without replacing or modifying either tool, escaping the colons is a necessary processing step.